# Is the SharePoint Online REST API for metadata update returning valid response codes?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I am updating metadata of a documentSet using below API endpoint.

> [https://con.sharepoint.com/sites/Test_site/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='cs/R001')/ListItemAllFields](https://con.sharepoint.com/sites/Test_site/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl=%27cs/R001%27)/ListItemAllFields)

In the above url the documentSet 'R001' exists, and the HTTP Response Code received is **204**.  If the above update is done for a non existing record then the HTTP Response Code is **200**.  Shouldn't the SPO return NotFound (or BadRequest) for non-existent record. Is it good to rely on these responses to construct further logic?  Please advise.